# Forwarding Data

Tags: cognito-forms

I am using the free version on my website (www.marinorealestate.com) and using just one form. When data is entered on the form, it gets sent to Cognito (https://www.cognitoforms.com/MarinoRealEstate1/FreeHomeValuation).

I need the entry to go to my email address so I don't miss it.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your screen it will say Submission Settings.  Click there.  And then click Notification Emails and add your email.  You will see a little envelope, hover over that and it will change to an edit option.